# VBA EXCEL : IF value in cell same as pattern then

Tags: excel, vba, string

I have learned about Reg Exp . It can declare a pattern. So what I want to do is I have 1 unique series"57S050" and it can be differentiate with it size. from 10,20,30,40,50 and so on. so it will be like this.
57S05010, 57S05020, 57S05030 and etc.
so What I want to do is if range (B2:B10) have the start with "unique series" (pattern 57S050) then
. Offset(0, 3).Interior. Pattern = xlPatternGray75
. Offset(0, 4).Interior. Pattern = xlPatternGray75

Create a code to change cell based on another cell. but the cell has many unique series.

Comment: Try RegExp pattern `57S050\d\d`. What's the pattern of `unique series`?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use RegExp, `Left` and `Trim` is works. On the Active Sheet

```
Sub coloring()

For Each cell In Range("B2:B10")

  If Left(Trim(cell), 6) = "57S050" Then
    cell.Offset(0, 3).Interior.Pattern = xlPatternGray75
    cell.Offset(0, 4).Interior.Pattern = xlPatternGray75
  End If
Next cell
End Sub
```